# Java "The type DenseMatrix must implement the inherited abstract method Matrix.multiply(Vector)"

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm doing a project for school in which we are given one Abstract class `Matrix` and we have to implement the methods of `Matrix` in two different classes. I am working on a class `DenseMatrix` and I keep getting the error:

> The type DenseMatrix must implement the inherited abstract method Matrix.multiply(Vector)

even though I have a method `multiply(Vector)` in `DenseMatrix`.

Code (`DenseMatrix` first then `Matrix`):

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.*;

public class DenseMatrix implements Matrix{

    private int size=0; // size of the matrix- number of rows/columns
    private int nnz=0; // number of non-zero elements
    private double[][] data;

    // Constructor used to initialize the matrix (all elements to zero)
    DenseMatrix(int size){
        this.size=size;
        data=new double[size][size]; // all elements take the values 0.0d
    }

    // Constructor with Random generator (using nnz random non-zero numbers           between 0.01<= x < 1.01
    // on any random row,column coordinates)
    DenseMatrix(int size,int nnz){
        ///=====> TO COMPLETE <===========///
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i =0; i<nnz;i++){
            double randomValue = (double)(.01 + r.nextDouble());
            int xCord = (int)(r.nextInt()*size);
            int yCord = (int)(r.nextInt()*size);
            data[xCord][yCord] = randomValue;
        }
    }

    // Constructor from any other matrix storage using the interface to Dense storage
    DenseMatrix(Matrix A){
        this.size=A.getSize();
        this.nnz=A.getNnz();
        data=new double[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
            data[i][j]=A.get(i,j);
        }
    }

    // get the size of the matrix
    public int getSize(){return size;}

    // get the number of non-zero elements
    public int getNnz(){return nnz;}

    // Assign the value x to element i,j
    public void set(int i,int j, double x){
        if ((data[i][j]==0)&&(x!=0.0)) nnz++;
        if ((data[i][j]!=0)&&(x==0.0)) nnz--;
        data[i][j]=x;
    }

    // get the value of the element i,j
    public double get(int i, int j){
        return(data[i][j]);}

    // Print matrix using a specific format
    public void display(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Display in dense format");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
                System.out.format("%.4f ",get(i,j));
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // get the elements of the diagonal
    public double[] getDiagonal(){
        ///=====> TO COMPLETE <===========///
        double[] diag = new double[size];
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
            diag[i] = get(i,i);}
        return diag;
    }

    public Vector multiply(Vector B){
        ///=====> TO COMPLETE <===========///
        double temp[] = new double[size];
        Vector result = new Vector(size);
        for(int y = 0;y<size;y++){
            for(int x = 0;x<size;x++){
                temp[y] = temp[y] + get(x,y);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
            result.set(i,(double)B.get(i) * temp[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

}



public interface Matrix {
    // Assign the value x to element i,j
    void set(int i,int j, double x);
    // get the value of the element i,j
    double get(int i, int j);
    // Extract the diagonal of the matrix
    double[] getDiagonal();
    // get the size of the matrix-- number of rows
    int getSize();
    // get the number of non-zero elements
    int getNnz();
    // Multiply a matrix by a vector
    Vector multiply(Vector B);
    // Print matrix using a specific format
    void display();
}
```

Comment: Do you have another class `Vector` somewhere which is used for the `Matrix` interface instead of the one from java.util? Maybe something left over from testing or from another project?

Comment: Yes I do have a vector class but it does not use the Matrix interface

Comment: The Vector class, which you have, is different from the java.util.Vector class?

Comment: Yup! Thank you. Deleted the vector class I had and now I don't have an error!

Comment: Please do not self-vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have used two different `Vector` classes. The method `DenseMatrix.multiply(Vector)` together with the `import java.util.Vector;` (from the beginning of the file) actually is `DenseMatrix.multiply(java.util.Vector)`. If you have another `Vector` class for instance in package `mypackage`, and you use that in the `Matrix` interface, the method would be `Matrix.multiply(mypackage.Vector)`. `multiply(java.util.Vector)` is different from `multiply(mypackage.Vector)`. You need to make sure, that you use the same Vector class for DenseMatrix and Matrix.

Comment: So I do have another Vector class but that class has to be redefined for the purpose of the project. Is there anyway that I can use my Vector class instead of the one from java.util?

Comment: Just remove the import for java.util.Vector and replace it with the import for your Vector class. If your Vector class is in the same package as DenseMatrix, you likely don't need an import statement. (The import java.util.* may cause issues as it imports Vector, you may want to import the classes from java.util individually and not with the wildcard `*`.)